# Definir idioma em index.php

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando desenvolver um sistema muito simples, contém 5 idiomas diferentes, essa parte funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que quando eu entro pela primeira vez no site, neste caso o ficheiro é o `index.php`, ele mostra o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de escolher um idioma qualquer, fica normal, só acontece quando entro pela primeira vez. A minha dúvida é: como é que eu faço para definir "português" logo assim que a página acaba de carregar, por exemplo o url ser `http://localhost:8080/.../?lang=pt`? 
Isto é uma parte do código:

```
<select id="lang" name="lang" onchange="submitForm()">
                    <?php
                    switch ($_GET['lang']) {
                        case 'en':
                        $lng=1;
                        break;
                        case 'fr':
                        $lng=2;
                        break;
                        case 'sp':
                        $lng=3;
                        break;
                        case 'de':
                        $lng=4;
                        break;
                        default:
                        $lng=0;
                    }
                    $questao=array('Portugues','ingles','frances','espanhol','alemao');
                    ?>
                    <option value="pt"<?php if($_GET['lang'] != 'fr' && $_GET['lang'] != 'en' && $_GET['lang'] != 'sp' && $_GET['lang'] != 'de'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Português</option>
                    <option value="en"<?php if ($_GET['lang'] == 'en'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>English</option>
                    <option value="fr"<?php if($_GET['lang'] == 'fr'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Français</option>
                    <option value="sp"<?php if($_GET['lang'] == 'sp'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Español</option>
                    <option value="de"<?php if($_GET['lang'] == 'de'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Deutsch</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="pergunta" align="center">
                <hr>
                <?php echo $questao[$lng]; ?>
                <hr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

Comment: Como o parâmetro `lang` não existe, ocorre o erro. Antes do `<select>` adicione `<?php $lang = isset($_GET["lang"]) ? $_GET["lang"] : false; ?>` e substitua os demais `$_GET["lang"]` por `$lang`.

Comment: Muito bom Valdeir, muito obrigada, funcionou na **perfeição**!  Era mais simples do que pensava!

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando PHP 7 pode utilizar o operador de coalescência:

```
 $lang = $_GET["lang"] ?? 'pt';
```